# Java Hibernate HQL to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a class that uses Hibernate HQL queries. I would like to change these into Hibernate Criteria queries.
However, Hibernate Criteria is a lot harder for me to understand than HQL, even with tutorials. Could someone show me how one of the queries would look like using Hibernate Criteria/Filters?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure().setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                                  configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("from TABLENAME WHERE IDObject1= :idObjectA" +
              "AND IDObject2= :idObjectB AND IDSettingOption = :idSettingOption");
query.setParameter("idObjectA", idObjectB);
query.setParameter("idObjectB", idObjectB);
query.setParameter("idSettingOption", idSettingOption);

List results = query.list();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your table description?

Comment: @atteij the status of the question is 'changed to solved' when you select one of the answers.

Comment: Your answers are using "Hibernate Criteria" not "JPA Criteria" (they are different). Suggest you clarify your question if you want Hibernate-specific, or a JPA provider-independent answer ... and remove the "jpa" tag from the question if you want Hibernate Criteria

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that it meant the same. I am looking for Hibernate criteria, that are still compatible with JPA. I will edit my question

Comment: Thank Paul:) I will do that when everything is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria( TABLENAME.class );

criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "IDObject1" , idObjectB) );
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "IDObject2" , idObjectB) );
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "IDSettingOption" ,idSettingOption) );

List results = criteria.list();
```

Here you can read about Criteria API, it has a lot of examples:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Thank your for your answer:) Finally a clear and simple example. I can certainly use this

Comment: Not "using JPA Criteria/Filters" like the question asked?

Comment: What do you mean? It does use criteria, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Attiej: This is using Hibernate Criteria API, not JPA. Anyway, you are using Hibernate's `Session` instead of JPA's `EntityManager`.

Comment: My mistake, I meant Hibernate Criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Entity.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("IDObject1", idObjectA))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("IDObject2", idObjectB))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("idSettingOption", idSettingOption))
    .list();
```

Comment: Not "using JPA Criteria/Filters" like the question asked?

Comment: i assumed hibernate is used directly in this scenario because of the code posted. You are right that the rest of the question implies JPA